# Why removing of spaces fails with multiple select field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have universal code to remove spaces at the beginning and at the end of field value:

```
var fieldValue = $('#'+fieldName).val().replace(/\s+$/g, '');
```

But in case `<select multiple="multiple"` field is passed, it fails.

Can I have universal code to bypass such fields?

Comment: `$('#'+fieldName)` what is fieldName ? and what are you trying to do ?

Comment: He's trying to ltrim and rtrim extra characters in each of the selectable options in the select list box.

Answer (score 1):

Given a select multiple, the `val()` method will return an **array** (unless no items are selected, in which case it will return `null`), not a string.

If you want to strip the whitespace from the values, you will have to loop over the array (possibly using [`each`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), or jQuery's [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)) and apply your regular expression to each value in turn.

Answer (score 0):

[val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

In the case of  elements, the `.val()` method returns an array containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#'+fieldName).val()` on `<select multiple>` returns array

You could use

```
var value = $.map( $('#'+fieldName).val(), function (opt) {
  return $.trim(opt);
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change both the value and the inner text of all options, regardless of whether they are selected or not:

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option name="1" value="Test 1 ">Test 1  </option>
    <option name="2" value=" Test 2">  Test 2</option>
    <option name="3" value=" Test 3 ">  Test 3  </option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">

    // Iterate through the individual option elements
    $("#mySelect option").each(function () {

        // "this" points to the option element encountered during the current iteration of .each()

        // Trim each text node (in between the <option> and </option> tags)
        // Using native JS String Object .trim()
        $(this).text( $(this).text().trim() );

        // Trim each value attribute
        $(this).val( $(this).val().trim()) });

    });

</script>
```

After the script is run you will get the following HTML, ensuring that all data whether selected or not will be trimmed as desired before form submission/Ajax request:

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option name="1" value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
    <option name="2" value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
    <option name="3" value="Test 3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

To make this universal, you could add a check to see if the element is a select element (and then do the .each() method above) or default to the more simple method of trimming a single element's text or value fields.

```
function trimInputs(fieldId) {
    var el = $('#' + fieldId);

    if (el.prop('tagName') === 'SELECT') {
        $('#' + fieldId + ' option').each(function () {        
            $(this).val( $(this).val().trim()) });
            $(this).text( $(this).text().trim() );
        });
    } else {
        el.val( el.val().trim() );
        el.text( el.text().trim() );
   }
}
```